# How to display just one alert message using two Ajax Get requests?

Tags: javascript, alert, display, get-request

I am using two Ajax Get requests, and each one has an if condition, in case any do not apply, I must save the reason and display it in just one alert message. But I am displaying two alerts, each for one get request. Here is my code:

```
    var errorMessage = "";

  $.get(url, function (responseGET) {
    var responseGETHtml = $(responseGET).find(".data-table tbody").html();

    console.log("responseGETHtml", responseGETHtml, typeof responseGETHtml);
    var rowCount = $(responseGETHtml).filter("tr").length;

       if (rowCount > 1) {
      errorMessage +=
        "There is more than one result for invoice #" + invoiceId + "\n";
    }
  });

  var url2 = "/einnahmen/" + customerId;
  url = url2.trim();
  $.get(url2, function (responseGET) {
    var responseGETHtml2 = $(responseGET).find(".data-item-form form.form");
      
  
    if (brutto < csvBrutto) {
      errorMessage += "Brutto of csv is bigger than Brutto in table" + "\n";
    }

    if (errorMessage != "") {
      alert(errorMessage);
    } else {
      responseGETHtml
        .find(".form-choice .forminput-zahlungsweise")
        .prop("checked", true)
        .val("Überweisung");

      $.post({
        url: "/einnahmen/?filter[rechnung_nr]=" + invoiceId,
        data: responseGETHtml.serialize(),
        success: function (responsePOST) {
          alert($(responsePOST).find(".message").text());
        },
        dataType: "html"
      });
    }
  });
```

How can I do to display just one alert message, containing all the errors?

Comment: bruh u have alert twice

Comment: `alert($(responsePOST).find(".message").text());`

Comment: but the first alert has a conditional if

Comment: well yea the condition gets carried out

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to use Promises and in particular [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

1. Let's transform each request in a promise which will resolve no matter of the result of the request but with the `errorMessage` as parameter.
2. Use Promise.all() on those promises, this new promise will resolved when both requests have resolved
3. If one, or more, request gave an error, join error message(s) if not resume your code

```
  const request1 = new Promise(resolve => {
    $.get(url, function(responseGET) {
      var responseGETHtml = $(responseGET).find(".data-table tbody").html();

      console.log("responseGETHtml", responseGETHtml, typeof responseGETHtml);
      var rowCount = $(responseGETHtml).filter("tr").length;

      const errorMessage = rowCount > 1 ? `There is more than one result for invoice #${invoiceId}` : '';

      resolve(errorMessage);

    });
  });

  var url2 = "/einnahmen/" + customerId;
  url = url2.trim();
  const request2 = new Promise(resolve => {
    $.get(url2, function(responseGET) {
      var responseGETHtml2 = $(responseGET).find(".data-item-form form.form");

      const errorMessage = brutto < csvBrutto ? 'Brutto of csv is bigger than Brutto in table' : '';

      resolve(errorMessage);

    });
  });

  Promise.all([request1, request2]).then(errorMessages => {

    // this code is executed when both request has resolved

    // has at least one request resolved with an error message ?
    const hasError = errorMessages.some(error => error != '');

    if (hasError) {
      alert(errorMessages.join('\n'));
    } else {

      // this code is executed when both request has resolved with no error.   

      responseGETHtml
        .find(".form-choice .forminput-zahlungsweise")
        .prop("checked", true)
        .val("Überweisung");

      $.post({
        url: "/einnahmen/?filter[rechnung_nr]=" + invoiceId,
        data: responseGETHtml.serialize(),
        success: function(responsePOST) {
          alert($(responsePOST).find(".message").text());
        },
        dataType: "html"
      });
    }


  });
```